# why accent dont display correctly when import my database?

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have an application made ​​in drupal, when I import my data with PHPMyAdmin  and then import for the site  that published the ñ and accents are not displayed correctly, I did the same to another machine and it worked OK, the difference in my mysql and the site is  posted is the collation  is utf8_unicode_ci for my machine and the  area of ​​the website is published  utf8_general_ci, this can cause the malfunction?? thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use utf8_general_ci while importing data to prevent errors with accents/acutes/tildes etc.

Comment: this means that this must be the explanation of the problem??

Comment: yes...when working with unicode charcters, the DB collation should be set to utf8_general_ci